# Detecting a triangle mesh fence in the foreground of an image

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I'm interesting in detecting a triangular mesh fence present in the foreground of a sequence of images. I've included an example image below. Ideally I'd like to output the grid of intersection points; this would then provide me with the distance to and orientation of the mesh (since the dimensions of the mesh are known and fixed).

As in the example image, the mesh can be obscured (by the thick black bars going horizontally and vertically) or can be confused with the background (see the black-lines of the structure in the top-left of the image). But the mesh will always completely cover the image, i.e. the edges or the outside of the mesh are never in view.

Any ideas on how one might begin to tackle a vision problem like this?

[image: Triangle mesh example]

Answer (score 1):

1. Find edge pixels
2. Hough transform to find lines in the image
3. Use ransac to find a model that describes the homography of the lines to the triangle grid.

Without more examples, it's hard to tell how difficult it would be to do.